# Error running mvn clean install

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, jboss6.x

using Eclipse to try and build a maven project with Eclipse. Anyway when I try to run mvn clean install I get the following error

```
     Failed to execute goal org.jboss.ws.plugins:maven-jaxws-tools-plugin:1.0.1.GA:wsconsume (default) on project sso: Error while running wsconsume: Process terminated with code 1
```

Its calling a MojoExecutionException.

Anyway I am getting the code from a subversion repository which works for others so its not the pom file. I done some googling and it mentions it could be the JBoss version I have running which could be causing the issue. I am using JBoss6.1.0. Also using Maven 3.0.4

Anyone have any ideas? If you need more info just let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: Full stack trace

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.ws.plugins:maven-jaxws-tools-plugin:1.0.1.GA:wsconsume (default)                     on project sso: Error while running wsconsume: Process terminated with code 1 -> [Help 1]
      org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jboss.ws.plugins:maven-jaxws-tools-plugin:1.0.1.GA:wsconsume (default) on project sso: Error while running wsconsume
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
  Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error while running wsconsume
    at org.jboss.ws.plugins.tools.AbstractWsConsumeMojo.execute(AbstractWsConsumeMojo.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Process terminated with code 1
    at org.jboss.ws.plugins.tools.WSContractDelegate.runConsumerOutOfProcess(WSContractDelegate.java:133)
    at org.jboss.ws.plugins.tools.WSContractDelegate.runConsumer(WSContractDelegate.java:99)
    at org.jboss.ws.plugins.tools.AbstractWsConsumeMojo.execute(AbstractWsConsumeMojo.java:149)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Well figured it out anyway. Turns out it was a windows limitation with file names. The file path was too long. As such once I moved it to a folder just below root, eg. C:/folder_here then it worked. Also switched to JDK 1.7 because another problem with windows means that if you use 1.6 you need to download another couple of jars. Anyway hope this helps someone else out.